# A quartic polynomial whose Galois group is Klein 4 is reducible.

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to prove the following statement.

> Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a quartic polynomial with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Show that $f(x)$ is reducible modulo every prime $p>3$.

I don't know how to approach. It seems $f(x)$ need not to be even irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. I will appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Otherwise construct two distinct quadratic subfields and show that the roots of $f$ are in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{u},\sqrt{v}][c^{-1}]$. We always have $\sqrt{u},\sqrt{v} \in \Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ thus $f$ splits completely in $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ for $p \nmid  c$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial which, when reduced mod $p$, has an irreducible factor of degree $n$. Then the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ has an $n$ cycle. For instance, you can see this in Lang's algebra, page 274. Since the Klein four group only has elements of order $2$, this should get what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!(+1)  Let me restate your answer :)  

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a quartic polynomial with Galois group of Klein four group.  Assume that $f$ is irreducible mod some prime $p>3$. Then the Galois group of $f$ mod $p$ over ${\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$ has order $4$ element. Since there is a embedding of the latter Galois group to first Galois group, Klein four group should have order 4 element which is a contradiction.

Comment: @LevBan That's correct. But you don't need the assumption $p>3$. It works for $p=2$ and $p=3$ all the same.